What's happening with Poseidon's request for an apology in Jorge Rivera-Herran's "Epic"'s "Ruthlessness"?
In Jorge Rivera-Herrans's musical "Epic", based on the events of the Odyssey, there's a song called "Ruthlessness", where Poseidon shows up to take revenge on Odysseus and his crew for leaving Polyphemus the cyclops blind. At some point during the song, we have this series of lines:

POSEIDON:
And now it is finally time to say goodbye, today you die
Unless, of course, you apologize
For my son's pain and all his cries
ODYSSEUS:
Poseidon, we meant no harm
We only hurt him to disarm him
We took no pleasure in his pain
We only wanted to escape
POSEIDON:
The line between naïveté and hopefulness is almost invisible
So close your heart, the world is dark and
Ruthlessness is mercy
Die.

What's going on in this scene? Is Poseidon's offer of mercy if they apologize genuine - despite his statement slightly beforehand that "Unlike you, I've no mercy left to give"? If so, why didn't Odysseus' apology qualify? What does "the line between naïveté and hopefulness is almost invisible" mean in this context?
What's happening here?

The refrain of the song is “ruthlessness is mercy upon ourselves”, that is, it is better to kill our enemies than to spare them (“ruthlessness”), so that we do not later suffer their attempts at revenge (“mercy upon ourselves”). Poseidon pointed this out earlier in the song:

Poseidon But [you] won’t kill and don’t get the job done
I mean you totally could have avoided all this
Had you just killed my son.

That is, the lesson Poseidon draws from the situation is that Odysseus should have killed Polyphemus, instead of merely blinding him. A dead Polyphemus wouldn’t have been able to beg his father to take revenge on Odysseus.
Note that the dramatic situation in the musical is very different from the situation in the Odyssey. In the poem, Odysseus and his men would surely have killed Polyphemus if they had been able to do so, but blinding was the severest harm that they were physically capable of inflicting on the giant. By contrast, in the musical, the Greeks had Polyphemus at their mercy and could have killed him if they wished, but Odysseus spared him against the advice of Athena:

Athena Have you forgotten the lessons I taught you?
He’s still a threat until he’s dead
Finish it.
Odysseus No.
Athena No?
Odysseus What good would killing do
When mercy is a skill more of this world could learn to use?

This re-interpretation of Odysseus’ character, as someone overly inclined to mercy with tragic consequences, is one of the main themes of the musical. In the opening number, Odysseus balked at the idea of killing Hector’s infant son Astyanax, and Zeus had to bolster his resolve:

Zeus This is the son of none other than Troy’s very own prince Hector
Know that he will grow from a boy to an avenger
One fueled with rage as you’re consumed by age
If you don’t end him now you’ll have no one left to save

So in this dramatic context, where the agon is between the mercy of Odysseus, and the pitilessness of the gods, Poseidon’s offer to spare Odysseus if he apologizes is not sincere. Poseidon is merely playing with Odysseus by offering him false hope. When he says, “The line between naïveté and hopefulness is almost invisible”, he means that he can’t tell whether Odysseus’s attempt to apologize is naïve (Odysseus believes Poseidon’s offer is sincere) or merely hopeful (Odysseus knows that Poseidon’s offer is insincere but apologizes anyway in the hope that his words can soften Poseidon’s heart).
Again, this does not reflect Odysseus’ character in the Odyssey, where he is depicted as a liar and a trickster. The poem has no scene in which Odysseus converses with Poseidon, but if it did, then we would surely interpret his words to Poseidon as a strategem.

My personal opinion is that the idea of Odysseus being overly inclined to mercy is nonsensical. The sack of Troy, the raid on the Cicones, the slaying of the suitors, the complicity in the murder of the maids, the fight with the men of Ithaca and the killing of Eupeithes—these are not the actions of someone inclined to mercy! But adaptations are free to introduce their own ideas.
